# undefined method for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can add a column with custom data type using the following code

```
def change
  add_column :assessorials, :metric_type, :assessorial_metric_type
end
```

The above code adds a new `metric_type` column of type **assessorial_metric_type** to the assessorials table

Now i have to create a new table which contains a column `metric_type` of type **assessorial_metric_type**

I have tried the following code.

```
create_table :charges do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.assessorial_metric_type :metric_type
end
```

This gives the error
**undefined method `assessorial_metric_type' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:**

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  t.column :metric_type, :assessorial_metric_type
```